# What's the issue with TwitterOAuth in twitteR (R package)?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using the R package twitteR to retrieve twitter data.

[The manual says](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf):

> the function "registerTwitterOAuth" is deprecated

and

> the function "setup_twitter_oauth" is called for its side effect.

What's the problem with them?

Comment: @Suseika it's not an error... It's the manual warns me that function has certain risk.

Answer (score 3):

`setup_twitter_oauth` is the function you want to use. It's true you call it for it's sideeffect - the side effect being the fact that it'll authorize you to make calls to the Twitter API.  You have to pass it your keys/secrets/tokens as per its function documentation.

I store these values in options so that when I need to authenticate I simply call

```
setup_twitter_oauth(getOption('twitter_consumer_key'),
                    getOption('twitter_consumer_secret'),
                    getOption('twitter_access_token'),
                    getOption('twitter_access_secret'))
```

Comment: Thank you @daattali. What does getOption do? I read a little about it and didn't get it...

Comment: @YujiZhang `getOption` is how you can access the individual `option` settings. you can see all the options by running `options()` or get single ones with `options('prompt')`, for example, but this returns a _list_ of length 1, so it is recommended to use `getOption('prompt')` which returns a _vector_ of length 1

Comment: The `getOption` trick is a good idea. To create/add/update an option, you can use `option('twitter_consumer_key' = 123567)`.

Comment: Thanks guys! why you wanna store the key and the secret in the option? So that people can't see it? @rawr

Comment: Exactly. I have my .Rprofile file set these options so that it's only available on my computer. This way I can post my code or have it on github without worrying that other people can use my credentials